# Problem when i shutdown the system or reboot with Linux Mint 18.1 KDE

Tags: linux-mint, kde, shutdown, reboot, amd-graphics

Anytime i try to shutdown or reboot the system, desktop and everything is closed but this appear:

[image: screen capture]

The system is blocked and i'm obliged to shutdown the Notebook manually with the button, i have fear that with doing this anytime i will break the system.

Solutions?

Info: Notebook: HP 15-ba054nl
Chipset: AMD A10-9600P RADEON R5, 10 COMPUTE CORES 4C+6G Ram: 16gb ddr4  sdram OS: Linux Mint 18.1 KDE 64 bit
kernel: 4.4.0-92-generic
KDE Plasma: 5.8.7

Answer (score 1):

See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=234232

with the same error with the user there answering his own question:

> It is a bug please see:
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/+bug/1608042
>   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1579374
>
> To get rid of it I installed a newer kernel with this manual:
>   http://www.yourownlinux.com/2016/11/how-to-install-linux-kernel-4-8-6-in-linux.html

Possibly now, the latest kernel version in the Mint repositories already have the fixes.

Answer (score -3):

I found these comments ([source1](https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm/issues/130#issuecomment-89572413), [source2](https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm/issues/130#issuecomment-89577513)) by Clement Lefebre (Mint's chief developer) which might be helpful:

> It hangs because the MDM slave fails to detect that the
>   x-session-manager has died (you can see that in the process list..
>   it's "defunct").
>
> The way that normally works is that MDM receives a SIGCHLD signal from
>   its child process x-session-manager. Now.. if anything you're running
>   intercepts SIGCHLD signals, that can mess with this. I recently worked
>   on gnome-keyring 3.14 for instance, which had that problem.
>
> GNOME/gnome-keyring@a942c8f
>
> Is there anything you're running messing with sigaction calls and/or
>   intercepting SIGCHLD signals? If in doubt, try to remove what you
>   installed (teamviewer for instance) and try to reproduce the issue
>   more and more with less and less applications running to see which one
>   could be causing this problem.
>
> Here's a quick way to troubleshoot it:
>
> Save this script http://pastebin.com/ggzU6U7V into a new file called
>   check_signals and make it executable.
>
> Next, run check_signals on the process IDs you suspect. It will tell
>   you if they intercept SIGCHLD.
>
> For instance, if I run check_signals on my MDM slave process (the
>   parent mdm process is the daemon, the child one is the slave), I get:
>
> Ign: SIGUSR1 (10), SIGPIPE (13), SIGPWR (30) Cgt: SIGINT (2), SIGUSR2
>   (12), SIGTERM (15), SIGCHLD (17), SIGXFSZ (25), SIGNUM32 (32),
>   SIGNUM33 (33)

Comment: How has that any relevance to the question?

Comment: amanda idhu relevant tha ena panuva.